Filtering out the point cloud in specific range
I have a problem to be solved. Can someone please let me know how to achieve it? I have generated a 3D structure of an object with the help of an open source software "Mesh room".The file saved in my computer is the "obj" file. I imported the obj file in Blender 4.2 and converted it into a point cloud. Each point has x,y,z values. I have to filter out the (x,y) belonging to a specific z range and plot the object of that particular z range value again.

What exactly is your goal, what do you want to achieve? Is it relevant that you have an .obj file imported from Meshroom? What do you mean by "filtering out" the x and y values?
